# How To Add Questions For Profiles In phpBB?

Tags: phpbb

i was setting up a phpBB Forum and i was looking at some forums and they have questions (you can ask me for examples if wanted)

there are questions such as favourite os

so how do i get questions like that?

thanks, will

Answer (score 0):

They are custom profile fields that can be added via your ACP.

```
ACP -> Users and Groups tab -> Custom profile fields
```

You are able to define the type of field (text, number, date, etc), where it should be displayed, whether its mandatory to fill, if they get asked at registration, plus lots more options. If you use more than one language on your board you can also localise them too.